# Dangling else problem

Tags: compilers, parsers

I was reading a book about compiler design, then in the CFG section, they introduced the dangling-else problem. They offered to match the the `else` with the last `if`. I still don't see how this solves the problem. Can somebody give me an explanation?

I searched before I put the question and none answered my question

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what the dangling-else problem is, how "match the last if" solves it or how the given grammar implements this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code is ambiguous. You can interpret it either as

```
If C1 then
   If C2 then
     S1
   else
     S2
```

or as

```
If C1 then
   If C2 then
     S1
else
   S2
```

The compiler needs to choose one way and covert it into machine language. The solution of "choose the last if" means the compiler will choose solution number 1 -- will attribute the "else" to the last (open, non-matched) "if" statement.

Comment: Thanks, but how do they solve such a problem? By implementing brackets?

Answer (score 0):

The language in question uses a grammar. The grammar is ambigous. However, the language can have rules that are not represented in the grammar (which means the actual language is not the language implied by the grammar but slightly different), and the compiler may implement other rules than just those represented by the grammar.

In this case, there is an additional rule: "If an else could match two if's according to the grammar, then it matches the last if". That solves the problem.

The alternative is to modify the grammar, as you saw. The alternative is the preferred solution in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a possible answer:

[After left factoring and making it unambiguous]

Let other = a

S -> iEtT | a

T -> S | aeS

I am generating all ***if's*** first and associating the ***else*** with the recent unassociated ***if*** .
If I have to get an ***else***, I should be eliminating the possibility of getting a new ***if*** between the current unassociated ***if*** and corresponding ***else***.
However I am allowing the possibility of getting an ***if*** after generating the corresponding ***else***.

Point out if there are any errors.

Thank you.